# Cannot delete topic successfully

Tags: apache-kafka

As far as I know version 1.0x and up, the config `delete.topic.enable=true` is the default configuration. Meaning, if I execute the delete command it should work as it expected.

However, I tried deleting the topic but it still there and was not deleted (when I describe the said topic in all brokers)

I read in some forums that I need to restart the broker servers and the zookeepers in order the deletion take effect.

Is there any other way to delete the topic without restarting the zookeeper and the brokers?

Comment: 1) Please add the broker and zookeeper process logs around the time you issue the topic delete command 2) Topics get "marked" for deletion. They are not immediately "dropped". And you never need to restart ZK to delete a topic's data/metadata.

Comment: In addition to what @cricket_007 said, make sure you don't have any consumer running which reads from the topic. It can happen that when you have auto.create.topic.enabled=true (not sure if this is the right name) that the consumers recreate the topic. But it would be empty than and onyl configured with the defaults.